# Javascript XMLHttpRequest: get div content form response

Tags: javascript

Hello in my app I'm trying to get some html content from other page

```
var city_name = encodeURIComponent(self.banners()[self.currentIndex].city.name);
var url = "http://www.example.com/banners?city=" + city_name;
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', url, false);   
req.send(null);  
var text = req.response;
```

On output I have some html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
     TEXT
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get content from output html's div?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
text.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].textContent;
```